# Durable settings of Screen timeout

Tags: settings, screen-timeout

I often set `Settings -> Sound & Display -> Screen timeout` to `never timeout`. When I turn off the device the settings is `1 minute` again.

Do you know how to make the settings durable? My version is 2.2 (Froyo)

Comment: my device is Archos 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you added apps and somehow changed some obscure setting. Nothing to do with firmware, whoops.

**Setting > About device > Repair and formatting tools - Delete device configuration and installed applications**

Failing that or if you're using it for reading & something similar. You should try one of those apps like "*Tasker*" where you can prevent screen dimming events during other apps of your choice. There's dozens (possibly hundreds) of apps that will keep your screen active.

- Screen On Toggler
- KeepScreen
- Setting Profiles
- Profile Scheduler
- FastBright (if you're having trouble with it routinely waking up and using power, once you've got it working right that is)

If you haven't already, go [here to Customer Service](http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/contact_support.html?country=us&lang=en) & contact the professionals that are paid to provide you with support. Perhaps this is a defective tablet.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, if you post the right answer, you should get the bounty. And considering that xralf, that asked the question, wrote a comment a few minutes ago, I  think it would be safe to say that he hasn't solved it yet

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread on archosfans.com about the precise issue you're having: http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=34624&view=previous

> I did a complete restore it started saving the screen timeout setting.

Comment: What is `complete restore`? If it's pushing the needle to the little hole, this didn't help.

Comment: @xralf: I wouldn't pretend that I am 100% sure what he meant, but my best guess is Factory Reset (Settings > Privacy > Factory data reset).

Comment: I accepted the other answer because I can't do `complete restore` now, but I believe that this could help too. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

A Verizon Customer Care person had me power down, power up in safe mode, then power down, power up normally. Now the timeout works as expected: 2 minutes is 2 minutes.